# Joining a rails table with a large number of records - causing my app to hang

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, scalability, scaling

I have an `actions` table with over 450,000 records. I want to join the `actions` table on the `users` table (it actually joins two other tables, one of which is joined on the other, and the other being joined on the `users` table, before joining the `actions` table.) The sql query looks like this:

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "campaigns" ON "campaigns"."user_id" = "users"."id" INNER JOIN "books" ON "books"."campaign_id" = "campaigns"."id" INNER JOIN "actions" ON "actions"."book_id" = "books"."id" AND "actions"."type" IN ('Impression')
```

However, this query in rails causes my app to hang because of the large number of records in the `actions` table.

How should I be handling this?

Comment: Do you need all 450k records at once? How about a limit?

Comment: @KreeK yes we do because we need to order users by the number of their actions

Comment: @user730569 then cache the action count. Add `action_count` to your users table that can store this number for you. Using your current implementation will forever cause you headache.

Comment: What indexes do your tables have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with this approach:

1. You are fetching the same users several times (users multiplied by
   number of actions)
2. You are fetching **all** the users with corresponding actions at once. It means big memory consumption and thus frequent garbage collection
3. You are fetching **all** the attributes for users. I guess, you do not need all them all
4. You have made comment about ordering users by their order count. Do you do this in Ruby code ? If yes, then it's the 4th problem. Big problem, indeed

So I'd propose to use group() method for grouping records or just plain SQL like

```
    SELECT "users".id, count(*) as actions_cnt
    FROM "users" 
        INNER JOIN "campaigns" ON "campaigns"."user_id" = "users"."id" 
        INNER JOIN "books" ON "books"."campaign_id" = "campaigns"."id" 
        INNER JOIN "actions" ON "actions"."book_id" = "books"."id" AND "actions"."type" IN ('Impression')
    GROUP BY
        "users".id
```

If there are many users in your app then I'd propose to add "OFFSET #{offset} LIMIT #{limit}" to fetch records in batches.

Finally, you can directly specify columns that you need so that memory footprint will be not so large.